Boolean using a two part pimitive is not cutting through like the other 3 instances
The fourth boolean is not cutting all the way through like the same object does on the other three holes. The boolean cutter is a cone and cylinder. It performs correct on three but not the 4th one. I dont know if its the 1st one or the last one.

How do I attach a blend file to this post? Here it is:


You can add a .blend file to your post by editing it and uploading the file to: https://blend-exchange.com/

Thanks. Hopefully this issue will get some attention.

Had I had normals displayed I would have caught this.
I used the scale of -1 to flip the object to what vertical transform I needed. That action had flipped the normals to point inward. This is what caused the Mesh Boolean to fail. The necessary correction was to add the Flip faces node to enable the normals to point outward.



Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.
